# Was Adam (as) predestined to eat from the forbidden tree?

Tags: jannah, surat-al-baqarah, adam-and-eve, khilafah, prophet-adam

Assalam o Alaikum brothers,

Someone just asked me a question, and to be frank, I didn't have a substantial reply. I'm also quiet confused now regarding this topic.

I understand that Allah swt in surah Baqarah 2:30 speaks about creating a Khalifa (vicegerent) on the earth. 
This was prior to creating Adam (as).

I understand that Allah Swt gave Adam (as) free will.

Iblees (Laanatallah Alayhi)  however, decieved Adam (as) to disobey Allah swt by eating from the forbidden tree. 
This is as I personally understand, the only reason for him to be expelled from heaven and sent down to earth.

Now here is where I'm confused astagfirullah! 
If Allah swt even prior to creating Adam (as) had already decided to send Adam (as) to earth as seen in Surah Baqarah 2:30.
Does this mean that Allah swt had pre destined Adam (as) to disobey? Because if He hadn't, and if Adam (as) wouldn't have disobeyed, he wouldn't be expelled from heaven right? Or would he be expelled regardless of his disobedience?

To summarize, from what little I understand, Allah prior to creating Adam(as)  willed to create a being whom he would place in the earth as a Khalifa.  But the only way that Adam (as) would be expelled is by disobedience to Allah. So Adam (as) didn't really have a choice?

And if Adam (as) didn't eat from the tree, would he still be in heaven?

Answer (score 1):

[Sahih al-Bukhari, Narrated Abu Huraira:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/82)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Adam and Moses argued with each other.
>   Moses said to Adam. 'You are Adam whose mistake expelled you from
>   Paradise.' Adam said to him, 'You are Moses whom Allah selected as His
>   Messenger and as the one to whom He spoke directly; yet you blame me
>   for a thing which had already been written in my fate before my
>   creation?"' Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said twice, "So, Adam overpowered
>   Moses."

[Jami` at-Tirmidhi, narrated that Abu Hurairah](https://sunnah.com/urn/634700)

> They said: 'O Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)! When was the Prophethood
>   established for you?' He said: 'While Adam was between (being) soul
>   and body.

From above Hadith:

- Adam: You (Moses) blame me for a thing which had already been written in my fate before my creation
- Prophet (SAW)-  Prophethood was established for me, While Adam was between (being) soul and body

And From Quran: before creating to Adam, Allah already announced to make a Khalifa on the earth(2:30).

Which proves that Allah already decided it. (which answer the title of your question).

**Does Adam have free will?**

Of course, he had free will. Allah did not force him or kept it hidden so Adam will eat from that tree by mistake and will come in that trap.

[Verse (2:35)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(2:35:12))

> And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat
>   therefrom in [ease and] abundance from wherever you will. But do not
>   approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers."

Allah clearly informed him and his wife, eat whatever you want **except from that tree**. And Allah is all knowing, so he already knew what Adam/Hauwa will do.

This point is not easy to explain, I accept me weeknes.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more brother? I'm not able to comprehend the answer accurately. Can I then understand that Allah swt made Adam (as) disobey Him without any choice. That is, Adam didn't really have a choice but to commit that mistake so as to get him expelled from Jannah?

Comment: "Allah has already written in his fate before his creation but gave the free will." That's a contradiction.

Comment: So Adam(as) was destined to live on earth just as Prophet Muhammed (Saw) was destined to be the final prophet of Allah. All of this was predestined much before Adam's creation. So regardless of Adam(as)eating the fruit, he would be sent to the earth at some point. Is that correct?

Comment: @Isnaan: that's what I understand from Quran and Hadith

Answer (score 0):

Allah already knows the future and it is all written down based on the free will of the person. For example, Allah already know what decision Adam (PBUH) would have taken so it has already been written down. Think of it as Allah already knows the future rather than not giving you the choice.

As for your question think of it like this, Allah has only given us the possibility to understand a small portion of what all is possible. A possibility I can think of is: Allah could have commanded Adam (PBUH) to go to earth and return after the 960 years and after the Day of Judgement.

Another option is that Allah wanted Adam (PBUH) to know what heaven would feel like and eventually planned for him to go to earth, and him eating from the tree cut short that time.

It is also said, that is when allah taught man how to ask for forgiveness. So it could have been that Allah already knew Adam(PBUH) would make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First point is what does '  Ard ' means... Is this means only this planet earth? . . explanation 1: Ard means land. So Whenever ALLAH Said I want to create a khalif on the land this not necessarily means planet earth.. It could be any land I think. May be land in the Jannah too where Adam A and Eve A were living with their human characteristics. And when a forgiven mistake occured by Adam A He and His Wife sent to this planet earth. 
If U read the Quran,  here Sama'a( sky) is a broad term used in many places according to situation.. Somewhere it indicates atmospheric layers, somewhere space with galaxies.. Same thing also applied to earth I think.. Earth means land,  earth means planet earth, earth means same planets like planet earth..

Explanation 2..  If Ard in those Ayats of Sura Bakara really indicates this planet earth then there may be another explanation. After ALLAH SWT Intended to send khalif on planet earth HE after creating Adam A and His wife  HE placed them on paradise for certain period. Also set exam for them there by tree and set destiny for them if they Disobey ALLAH's command then they will have to go to planet earth before the normal period of sending with a burden of disobeying command which is forgiven but a great lesson to them.  ALLAH SWT at that time didnot placed themselves there for eternity If He intends to send them to planet earth. But by disobeying ALLAH's command they came out of paradise before certain period .. Probably this can be an explanation.
 This is my personal view.. But only ALLAH KNOWS THE BEST.If I am wrong I ask forgiveness to ALLAH SWT.

Answer (score 0):

And for the person who said it’s a contradiction, that is totally wrong!!  If you’re driving your car and you come to a T intersection do you decide whether to go left or right? of course you do! God only knows the  decision you’re going to make, he gave you that brain.. then he knows if you’ll turn left or right at the next one and so on  Brother it’s not like the prophet Adam was destined to fail, where it was out of his control, no!! God didn’t make him eat the apple, but GOD  knew he would.. Just like when he created Ibliss, after centuries of worship, did God now he would eventually disobey him, ultimately?? Of course!!God is not surprised by his creations actions nor does he control them(excluding angels), he simply knows the choices we make when we make them... Adam a/s ate the apple, he gave him free will.... GOD IS GREAT

Comment: How can you say that is a contradiction???

Answer (score 0):

Now let us refer to the verses in which Allah revealed to understand the context of Surah Al-Baqarah, Ayah 30: “˹Remember˺ when your Lord said to the angels, “I am going to place a successive ˹human˺ authority on earth.” They asked ˹Allah˺, “Will You place in it someone who will spread corruption there and shed blood while we glorify Your praises and proclaim Your holiness?” Allah responded, “I know what you do not know.”(Surah Al-Baqarah, Ayah 30). Now what do we learn from this verse? Allah states that he is going to place a successive authority on earth, this is a future occurrence. Now we know that Allah is all-knowing, and so knows what Adam was going to do before he did it. Thus after committing the sin in which Allah knew Adam would commit, he would be sent down to earth, thus “a successive authority on earth” would be placed.